# Search algorithms always returns -1

Tags: java

I have the following implementation of binary and sequential search. I'm not very experienced with Java, and somehow implementation of both methods always returns -1 when searching an element:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class searchArrayDemo {

    private static int binarySearch(int[] inputArr, int key) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = inputArr.length - 1;

        while (start <= end) {

            int middle = (start + end) / 2;

            if (key < inputArr[middle]) {
                end = middle - 1;
            }

            if (start > inputArr[middle]) {
                start = middle + 1;
            }

            if (start == inputArr[middle]) {
                return middle;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        }

    // This function returns index of element x in arr[]
    private static int search(int arr[],int x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // Return the index of the element if the element
            // is found
            if (arr[i] == x)
                return i;
        }

        // return -1 if the element is not found
        return -1;
    }


    // Driver method to test above
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int c, n, array[];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements: ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        array = new int[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            array[c] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }
        System.out.println("Elements: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the element to be searched: ");
        int k = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("\nSelect type of search\n");
            System.out.println("1. Binary search");
            System.out.println("2. Sequential search");

        int choice = in.nextInt();
        int binarySearchResult = binarySearch(array, choice);
        int sequentialSearchResult = search(array, choice);
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                if (binarySearchResult == -1) {
                    System.out.println("\n" + k + " element not found");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("\n"+ k +" element found at position "+ binarySearchResult);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (sequentialSearchResult == -1) {

                    System.out.println(sequentialSearchResult + "");
                    System.out.println("\n" + k + " element not found");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("\n" + k + " element found at position " + sequentialSearchResult);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm suposing that this is some silly mistake, but can you please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: It seems that the `binarySearch()` is an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks for the replies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This

```
int binarySearchResult = binarySearch(array, choice);
int sequentialSearchResult = search(array, choice);
```

should be

```
int binarySearchResult = binarySearch(array, k);
int sequentialSearchResult = search(array, k);
```

Because `k` is the element you want to search for and `choice` is supposed to be the type of search. It's also worth noting that your `binarySearch` will not function correctly until you sort the `array`.

Comment: You've missed `if (start > inputArr[middle])`... also all look like "typograpical error" and don't need full answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Made the answer community wiki. Add it in... it's a little cruel (imo) to just close it as a typographical error (especially since OP is clearly just starting out).

Comment: Thanks, that's the thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to replace "start" with "key" in the if statements of the first function.  Also (side note), how does your function handle the scenario when start + end is odd and, also, is that how you want your function to handle that scenario?

Also, check your `start = middle + 1;`